# Simple UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, youtube, landscape

I'm making a tab bar app and one of the tabs is a youtube channel. It works fine and is perfect but the one problem is when i click on the video it plays but only in the standard view and not in Landscape. Any ideas on how to fix. Im sure its really simple but i've been having no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This question probably answers what you are trying to do:
[Webview resizes automatically to portrait and landscape view in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325795/webview-resizes-automatically-to-portrait-and-landscape-view-in-iphone)

The key thing to take away from it is that you need your view controller to tell the app that it supports the other orientations, not just portait.

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation 
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This helped but now the whole app is landscape if you tilt it. i just want the youtube video being played from the UIWebview to be landscape and everything else portrait... do you have any solutions for this...? Thanks again for helping me with this