# Text placement in a WebView

Tags: xcode, swift, webview

Any help would be great.  I have a WebView in a View Controller which in portrait mode works fine and displays the text which it is suppose to, the moment I rotate to landscape everything stays on the left.  How do I get the text which is centred in portrait to be centred in landscape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325795/webview-resizes-automatically-to-portrait-and-landscape-view-in-iphone%20%22this%20post%22?) you may find helpful. You're a little thin on details, but this might be a good place to start.

Additionally, I've found GitHub to be very helpful in learning syntax if it's not clear from Apple's documentation. You can search for code there and drill down on the language (Objective-C or Swift).

Comment: many thanks for your help I will give it a look.  Sorry if I was, a little thin on details.  But you are correct judging from your answer. In portrait everything is good but as soon as I turn it to landscape the web view maintains the same width and the right 1/4(more or less) of the screen is blank, so it is not resizing to fill in the new width in landscape.